# QtGui/QApplication No Such File or Directory

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian

I'm using QtSDK 1.1.3 (1,4GB)
I'm developing an apps for Symbian^3 Belle (Qt 4.7.4)

When i'm deploying with **Qt Simulator MinGW**, everything is fine.. i can control my apps in N8 simulator..

But, when i changed to **Qt 4.7.4 Symbian Devices**, everything is ruined.. several error message appeared..

here's some error message :

```
E:\HELL\Qt\BiQ\main.cpp:1: error: QtGui/QApplication: No such file or directory
```

I don't know what to do...

I'm using Windows7 32bit..
My default install path : C:\qtsdk\
My Project path : E\HELL\Qt

can anyone have any solution for my problem? 
thank you guys, really appreciate it.. :)

Comment: Do you have `#include "QtGui/QApplication"` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbian toolchains do not work across volume boundaries. Either move your source project to C: or the Qt SDK to E:.